# Get undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to use Microsoft server in a PHP program.  I downloaded the Microsift drivers for PHP for SQL Server, made sure that Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Client was installed, made sure the extension_dir value was correct in my PHP.ini file, and added extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll in the dyanmic extension section of my PHP.ini file.  Yet i still get the error 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()'.  I am running an apache server on windows 7 and downloaded the 3.0 version of the driver.

So what am I doing wrong? What else should I check for? If I am running under an Apache server, I don't need to do anything to IIS, do I?  Below is my PHP code.

```
      <?php
    // phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

     require_once 'serverlogin2.php';
    /* Specify the server and connection string attributes. */

      //$connectionInfo = array ("Database"=>$databaseName, "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd); 
      $connectionInfo = array ("Database"=>$databaseName); 

        /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
       $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo); 
       if( $conn === false )
       {
        echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
       }

       echo "made sql connection";
       return;

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`sqlsrv_connect` (sqlsrv extension) is [not available](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) in the GA branch, you need to get it from svn and compile it. You can also use the `mssql_connect` (mssql extension) or PDO.

Comment: What is the GA branch and what is svn?

Comment: svn is subversion which is a source code management tool, GA is generally available.

Comment: If I use the mssql_connect, do I need to download anything or is that part of the PHP extension?  I didn't see any mssql extensions in my PHP extension directory.

Comment: mssql connect is packaged in my default

Comment: http://th1.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php and also PDO is BETTER option http://th1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I will try the mssql_connect and see if that works.

Comment: I added the extension for mssql in the php.ini file and now I get the same error for mssql_connect.  What gives?  Do I have to close and restart the Apache server when changing the php.ini file?